# What's wrong if flutter doctor tells you: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory?

Tags: java, linux, flutter, flutter-doctor

Running `flutter doctor` at Android Studio's terminal prints:

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0-rc2)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more details.
```

Running the suggested `flutter doctor --android-licenses` command fails with:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/bin/java

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

Oddly enough, `which java` prints `/usr/bin/java` (which matchtes `JAVA_HOME`)

So it seems like *everything should be in order*... But why is Flutter unhappy with the path at `JAVA_HOME`? And how can it be fixed?

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` must point to the **folder** (directory) containing the Java Development Kit. `/user/bin/java` is a **file** (an executable) or possibly a symlink.

Comment: Do a `ls -l /usr/bin/java` and start following the links to the jdk base directory.  My Linux install has two hops to get to it.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly download Latest Available Android Tools from configure > SDK Manager > SDK Tools and make sure you have installed JDK properly then run flutter doctor --android-license.